# How to make array POST requests to API?

Tags: android

**For example I have an API like:**

Content-type: application/json

{

```
"survey_pages": [

    {
        "id": 1,
        "answers": [{"question": 4, "answer": true}, {"question": 2, "answer": 1}, {"question": 3, "answer": 1}, {"question": 1, "answer": "2014-03-18T00:01:30"}]
```

I was trying to make it through the Lists of NameValue Pair, but I can't do it, because there is no constructor of NameValue Pair for Objects.

The main problem is to pass "Array of Arrays" to setEntity method.

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("url");
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.accumulate("token", LogedInUserDetails.getToken());
json = jsonObject.toString();
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);
httppost.setEntity(se);
httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
```

You can add like this. create the desired format using json objects and json array and set the entity to the httppost.